# python pptx change table location post hok

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-pptx

I use python 2.7 with python pptx.

I know how to determine the table's location when creating it:

```
table = shapes.add_table(rows, cols, left, top, width, height).table
```

The problem is the following: i need the table to be centered, i can't find it's width and height before i create it, but after i create it, i can't move it, when trying the following code:

```
table.left = <some number>
```

This does not change anything.

How can i either:
1.calculate/determine the table width before creating it
2.move the table after it is already created.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is not the object with position and size. The object with position and size is the graphics-frame *shape* that *contains* the table object. To change the position and size you need a reference to the graphics-frame shape:

```
graphic_frame = shapes.add_table(rows, cols, left, top, width, height)
table = graphic_frame.table
graphic_frame.left = <some number>
```